# How to remove equation numbering in R Markdown

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown

I am new to R markdown. I have a simple question about how to remove the automated equation numbering in the output PDF. Use the following codes for example:

```
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} | (f + g )(x_i) - (f + g)(x_{i-1}) | &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} | \{ f(x_i) + g(x_i) \} - \{ f(x_{i - 1} + g(x_{i-1}) \} |
\\  &\leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} | f(x_i) - f(x_{i - 1} | + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} | g(x_i) - g(x_{i - 1})|
\\  &\leq  V(f, P) + V(g, P)
\end{align}
```

It will automatically label the three lines of equations with (1), (2), (3). How do I suppress the numbering?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How do you obtain this `align` environment in R Markdown? You have to use `align*` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I was actually looking up how to add numbering... so perfect info swap! Try:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} | (f + g )(x_i) - (f + g)(x_{i-1}) | &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} | \{ f(x_i) + g(x_i) \} - \{ f(x_{i - 1} + g(x_{i-1}) \} |
\\  &\leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} | f(x_i) - f(x_{i - 1} | + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} | g(x_i) - g(x_{i - 1})|
\\  &\leq  V(f, P) + V(g, P)
\end{aligned}
$$
```

This is more of a LaTeX thing than an RMarkdown thing: from my understanding, the $$ $$ isn't numbered, and the aligned environment is intended for use within other environments in order to display a single equation.

So, within the $$ $$ environment, you can use the aligned environment to display an equation, but it won't be numbered.

I missed the response from Werner earlier, but using align* works too. I guess the difference is the nuance in the initial intention.

(Also btw, this means if you use aligned within align, you get a block equation with only one number.)

Comment: Could you ad a short explanation of how you're suppressing the line numbering? Thanks!

Comment: I guess this more of a LaTeX thing than an RMarkdown thing. From my understanding, the $$ $$ isn't numbered, and the aligned environment is intended for being used within other environments for displaying a single equation. And so within the $$ $$ environment, you can use the aligned environment to display an equation, and it won't be numbered. I missed the response from Werner earlier, but using align* works too. I guess the difference is the nuance in the initial intention. (Also btw, this means if you use aligned within align, you get a block equation with only one number.)